# Interesting facts/ proofs about rational and irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, proof-explanation

We got set some work to find some interesting facts or proofs regarding rational and irrational numbers. I wonder if anyone could offer some insight or recommend a good book/ website to look at.

Comment: We don't know whether $e+\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: But we do know that one of $e +\pi$ or $e \pi$ is transcendental

Comment: thanks do you have any websites that explain this? With proofs and theory?

Comment: @Tk706 the fact I have written is easy to show if we assume that we know that $e$ is transcendental. Now assuming that if $e+ \pi$ and $e \pi$ were algebraic then the roots of $x^2-(e+ \pi)x+ e \pi=0$ are algebraic, which is a contradiction.

Comment: A book which might help you is A comprehensive course in Number Theory by Alan Baker. I found it very interesting and it covers continued fractions which can be used to give proofs of irrationality

Comment: Also you should look up Gelfond Schneider Theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem)

Comment: @SirJective : It seems that your example cannot be called a 'fact"..

Comment: I particularly like the proof that the set of rational numbers is not closed. This property allows the construction of $\mathbb {R} $ from the rationals

Comment: @JohnMa I think we can call it a fact because statement says
 We don't know whether $e+ \pi$ is transcendental over Q which if I am not wrong is not really known so is actually a fact

Comment: @happymath Actually we are talking about algebricity over $\mathbb{Q}$ so I don't understand how the fact that $e+\pi$and $e\pi$ are algebraic imply that the solution of the polynom $x^2-(e+\pi)x+e\pi$ will be algebraic?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the **Gelfond-Schneider theorem** interesting. The theorem states that:

> *If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a ≠ 0,1$ and $b$ non-rational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.*

This not only gives rise to trivial results such that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational, but to some more interesting ones as well. For instance, by taking $a=-1$ and $b=-i$, where $i=\sqrt {-1}$, we can obtain the following result:

$$
(-1)^{-i} = \left( e^{i \pi} \right)^{-i} = e^\pi,
$$

showing that $e^\pi$ is transcendental.

Answer (score 0):

The irrationality measure $\mu(x)$ of numbers such as $x=\pi$ or $x=e$ has been studied in detail, but there are still plenty of conjectures. You can find the definition of this measure, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html). In particular:

- $\mu(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational
- $\mu(x)=2$ if $x$ is algebraic of degree $> 1$
- $\mu(x)\geq 2$ if $x$ is transcendental

More results about $\mu(x)$:

[image]

Another topic of interest is non-periodic continued fractions for irrational numbers, for instance (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)):

[image]

Another surprising fact is a simple recurrence relation to compute all the digits of some quadratic irrationals (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537637/limit-associated-with-a-recursion-connection-to-normality-of-quadratic-irration)) which could potentially help determining whether they are [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number):

[image]

Resulting in

[image]

Here the $d_n$'s are the digits of $x$.

**Other results**

- If $x$ and $x'$ are irrational normal numbers linearly independent
  over the set of rational numbers, then the correlation between the
  binary digits of $x$ and $x'$ is equal to zero. See [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/state-of-the-art-statistical-science-to-address-famous-number-the).
- If $x$ is irrational, then the sequence $\{kx\}$ where
  $k=0,1,2\cdots$ and the brackets represent the fractional part
  function, are [equidistributed modulo 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).